# Infinite series sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the sum of $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos((2n-1)x)$$ and what is 
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\cos(2nx)$$
I have got the infinte series sum of $\cos x$  but didn't know how to get that.

Comment: I have edited your question. Please format your questions as I did with LaTeX or MathJax

Comment: and what is the " ... infinte series sum of  $\cos x$ ... " ?

Answer (score 2):

Since $a_n = \cos 2nx $ does not go to zero. So 
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos 2nx $$
diverges. What can you say about the other sum ?